# How to Extend Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I want to be able to extend the default implementation of IdentityRole to include fields like Description. It's easy enough to do this for IdentityUser because IdentityDbContext takes a generic parameter of type IdentityUser.  However, IdentityDbContext doesn't allow you to do this for IdentityRole.  How can I accomplish this?

I know I can create a basic DbContext, and implement my own IUserStore, so that I can use my own role class, but I really don't want to have to do that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have just gone through this pain myself. It actually turned out to be pretty simple. Just extend IdentityRole with your new properties.

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole(string name)
        : base(name)
    { }

    public ApplicationRole()
    { }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to add the line

```
new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

into your ApplicationDbContext class like this otherwise you will get errors.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {}

    new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

thats all I needed to do. Make sure you change all instances of IdentityRole to ApplicationRole including anything you are seeding. Also, dont forget to issue a "update-database" to apply the changes to your DB. Any existing rows in there won't be seen by your new RoleManager unless you have the "ApplicationRole" set as a discriminator. You can easily add this yourself.

HTH

Erik

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think I did everything except setting "ApplicationRole" as discriminator.
I was just wondering why this was done...
    new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

`UserManager<TUser>` uses `UserStore<TUser>` as its user store (`IUserStore`). `UserManager` works with `UserStore` for adding and removing user to a `role name` as IUserRole.

Likewise, there are interfaces `IRole` & `IRoleStore<TRole>` for `IdentityRole` and `RoleStore<TRole>` where `TRole` is `IdentityRole`. This is to work plainly with Roles directly.

So you can inherit `IdentityRole` and add additional information. Use `RoleStore<MyRole>` to manage it along additional information.

`RoleManager<TRole>` provides core interaction methods for Role, which can use MyRoleStore.

MyIdentityRole.cs

```
public class MyIdentityRole: IdentityRole
{
   public String Description { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for though.  I'm talking about the actual storage mechanism. IdentityDbContext allows you to use your own IdentityUser, but it forces the use of IdentityRole.

Comment: The above customization is same approach to IdentityUser except the store is RoleStore instead of UserStore. Both the store uses IdentityDbContext. IdentityDbContext, automatically takes those new fields in IdentityUser, but for IdentityRole you need to use OnModelCreating for providing Db mapping and constrains for new fields added to it.