# Issues with extending Asp.Net Identity IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In my MVC5 project, I have exteneded the `IdentityUser` class in my `DbContext` with the following implementation:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection") { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
               .ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .ToTable("Users");
        }
}
```

Using an `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool EmailIsConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

However, whenever I try to do the same thing and extend the `IdentityRole` class it is not working. If I simply create an `ApplicationRole` class that inherits from `IdentityRole` (and change all instances of `IdentityRole` in my MVC project to `ApplicationRole`), then no roles are returned from the database. For example, using the following

`RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));`

yields a result count of 0 when I call `RoleManager.Roles`.

Has anyone done this yet and could provide some guidance?

**UPDATE**
I had forgotten to change my DB Seed method to use my new `ApplicationRole` - it was still using `IdentityRole`. After doing so, I couldn't apply an update to my database because I kept getting a DBValidation error. After adapting some of the code from [this post](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/implementing-user-confirmation-and-password-reset-with-one-asp-dot-net-identity-pain-or-pleasure), I was able to get everything working by overriding the `ValidateEntity` method of the DbContext

Answer (score 3):

[How to Extend Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865245/how-to-extend-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityrole/19865985#19865985)

1. Make sure you are inheriting from `IdentityRole` for your `ApplicationRole`
2. Make sure you add following in your `ApplicationDbContext`, so that you work directly with your `ApplicationRole`.

   `new public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }`
3. You following the steps as follow

   - Enable-Migration
   - Add-Migration "InitialSetup"
   - Update-Database
   - Modify any model properties
   - Add-Migration "ModificationName"
   - Update-Database

---

Your code to create RoleManager is good now.

```
RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<ApplicationRole>(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
ApplicationRole role = roleManager.FindByName("Admin");
```

- `RoleManager<ApplicationRole>` do not have any property with name `"Roles"`
- `ApplicationDbContext` has a property named `"Roles"`. As you are followed Step 2, this property now returned as `DbSet<ApplicationRole>`

Comment: I have tried this exact same thing, but I always got a DbValidation error when I tried to update the database. I had to override the `ValidateEntity` method of my DbContext - I'll update my question soon

Comment: It is good you could solve your issue. Moreover, I just added the code to update the role.Description to database, it worked.