# Is there a way to create a custom User and Role without specifying the TKey on IdenitityUser, IdentityRole, and IdentityDbContext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Is there a way to create a custom User and Role without specifying the TKey `string` in `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole`, and `IdentityDbContext`? I ask because it seems to think I don't want the auto-generated primary key `Id` anymore and I absolutely do. Doing what I've done below, `UserManager.Create(user, password)` will fail with an `EntityValidationError` on `Id`.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin
{
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim
{
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProperName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public MyAppDb()
        : base("MyAppDb")
    {
    }

    public static MyAppDb Create()
    {
        return new MyAppDb();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is **"NO"**. If you specify the TKey on `User` and/or `Role` the primary keys are no longer created for you.

It seems I was trying to over-complicate things. Thanks @dima for helping me decide to un-complicate things. Here is what I did to successfully get users and roles (both with custom properties) to successfully work, i.e., to successfully create records in the database via a controller and view:

**UPDATE**: You may want to look at the link I provided at the bottom for a better/simpler solution.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin
//{
//}

//public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim
//{
//}

//public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
//{
//}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProperName { get; set; }
}


public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public MyAppDb()
        : base("MyAppDb")
    {
    }
}
```

However, a new issue has arose with the `UserManager`. Specifically, I'm getting the error `The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.` on this line of code `var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

**UPDATE**: Fixed this error here: [Why am I getting an IdentityRole error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796804/why-am-i-getting-an-identityrole-error)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning this new ASP.NET Identity system but have you tried omitting generic types like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

same goes for `ApplicationRole`

`MyAppDb` would look like this:

```
public class MyAppDb: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

By default the IDs will be strings with auto-generated GUIDs in the DB

Comment: I've created a custom role `ApplicationRole` and you have to specify it in the `MyAppDb: IdentityDbContext<...>`.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion, but had to create `MyAppDb` like this: `public class GEOdaisiaMembershipDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>` and got this error `The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.` on this line of code `var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` when registering a user.

Comment: take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865245/how-to-extend-microsoft-aspnet-identity-entityframework-identityrole)

Comment: you need to add it to the context `public DbSet<ApplicationRole> Roles { get; set; }`

Comment: I looked at that post you sent above and it doesn't help. I'm using AspNet.Identity2.0. The `AspNetRoles` table exists. And I've created a controller and view that successfully creates roles. I see them in the database.

Comment: So the user was created in the database. So why is `var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` having an issue? Hmmm. Maybe I've been looking at this stuff too long and my mind is too busy.

Comment: not sure, I've started learning ASP.NET Identity not so long ago myself so by trying to help you I'm actually in a way helping myself :) can I see how and where `CreateIdentityAsync` is set up?

Comment: Nope, because it is in the `UserManager`. The UserManager is instantiated like this: `UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyAppDb()));`

Comment: It is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace.

Comment: So, I suppose I have to answer this question now that I have Users and Roles both with custom properties on them, and both successfully being created in the database.  However, I will open a new question about what is now happening with `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)`. Thank you @dima you got me started down the right path--which was comment-out all this extra garbage I've been doing and keep it simple.

Comment: no problem, sorry I couldn't be more helpful since like I said this stuff is quite new to me too... also your best bet to also post a piece of code where you get the error, i.e. where you call `CreateIdentityAsync`

Comment: You were helpful. BTW, that line of code, is the line of code calling `CreateIdentityAsync()` that is producing the error. ;)